# Taming immutable data pipeline verboseness

Tags: java

I have a CSV conversion class. It's job is to muck with values and produce few outputs. The CSV row has around 30 columns. I've modelled via immutable objects:

```
In(i1, i2, ..., iM)
OutA(a1, a2, ..., aN)
OutB(b1, b2, ..., bO)
...
OutK(k1, k2, ..., kP)
OutX(x1, x2, ..., xQ)
```

There are inter-dependencies: b1 is the same as a1, b2 is calculated based on a2, they combine to the final result (`OutX`). Some calculations are expensive.

The end result is a huge method that looks similar to this simplified monster:

```
OutX method(In in) {
  I1 i1 = in.getI1();
  I1 i2 = in.getI2();
  ...
  I1 iM = in.getIM();

  A1 a1 = fa1(i1, i2);
  A2 a2 = fa2(i2, i5, iM);
  ...
  AN aN = ...;

  OutA outA = new OutA(
    a1,
    a2,
    ...,
    aN);

  A1 b1 = a1;
  B2 b2 = fb2(a2, i5, i13);
  ...
  BO bO = ...;

  OutB outB = new OutB(
    b1,
    b2,
    ...,
    bO);   

  ...

  return new OutX(
    outA,
    outB,
    ...,
    outK);
}
```

'Tis wonderful being immutable and type-checked and stuff. 'Tis also 300 lines and this is for each "flavor" of CSV. Ugh. Breaking up just creates methods that are mostly parameters + constructor calls.

Are there patterns or libraries to un-Frankenstein this?

Comment: Model a `Row` object using the Strategy Pattern and make the particular computations part of each concrete strategy?  The elements of the `Row`, if not reproducibly constant, could be modeled with the Type Safe Heterogenous Container pattern.

Comment: A variation on the Builder pattern might be useful.

Comment: ... But possibly more, not less, verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter pattern might be helpful.  Each layer/shell delegates as much as possible to build up to the final result.  Here's an example:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.process();
    }

    private void process() {
        In in = new In(1, 2, 3);
        OutA a = new OutA(in);
        OutB b = new OutB(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public class In {
        private final int i1;
        private final int i2;
        private final int i3;

        public In(int i1, int i2, int i3) {
            this.i1 = i1;
            this.i2 = i2;
            this.i3 = i3;
        }

        public int getI1() {
            return i1;
        }

        public int getI2() {
            return i2;
        }

        public int getI3() {
            return i3;
        }
    }

    public class OutA {
        private final In in;
        private Integer a3;

        public OutA(In in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public int getA1() {
            return in.getI1();
        }

        public int getA2() {
            return in.getI2() * 2;
        }

        public int getA3() {
            if (a3 == null) {
                // a3 = some expensive calculation
                a3 = 1; // hold the value to avoid expensive calculation next time method is called
            }
            return a3;
        }
    }

    public class OutB {
        private final OutA a;

        public OutB(OutA a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getB1() {
            return a.getA1();
        }

        public int getB2() {
            // a.getA3() is expensive, but only the first time it's called
            return a.getA3() + 4;
        }

        public int getB3() {
            // a.getA3() is expensive, but only the first time it's called
            return a.getA3() + 9;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "b1: " + getB1() + " b2: " + getB2() + " b3: " + getB3();
        }
    }

}
```

Output: b1: 1 b2: 5 b3: 10

UPDATE:  here's a more interesting example using a factory to have different calculations, but still using the same interface.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.process();
    }

    private void process() {
        In in = new In(1, 2, 3);
        OutXFactory factory = new OutXFactory();

        OutX resultType1 = factory.create(in, CSVType.TYPE_1);
        System.out.println(resultType1);

        OutX resultType2 = factory.create(in, CSVType.TYPE_2);
        System.out.println(resultType2);
    }

    public class In {
        private final int i1;
        private final int i2;
        private final int i3;

        public In(int i1, int i2, int i3) {
            this.i1 = i1;
            this.i2 = i2;
            this.i3 = i3;
        }

        public int getI1() {
            return i1;
        }

        public int getI2() {
            return i2;
        }

        public int getI3() {
            return i3;
        }
    }

    public enum CSVType {
        TYPE_1, TYPE_2;
    }

    public class OutA {
        private final In in;
        private Integer a3;

        public OutA(In in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public int getA1() {
            return in.getI1();
        }

        public int getA2() {
            return in.getI2() * 2;
        }

        public int getA3() {
            if (a3 == null) {
                // a3 = some expensive calculation
                a3 = 1; // hold the value to avoid expensive calculation next time method is called
            }
            return a3;
        }
    }

    public class OutB {
        private final OutA a;

        public OutB(OutA a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getB1() {
            return a.getA1();
        }

        public int getB2() {
            // a.getA3() is expensive, but only the first time it's called
            return a.getA3() + 4;
        }

        public int getB3() {
            // a.getA3() is expensive, but only the first time it's called
            return a.getA3() + 9;
        }
    }

    public interface OutX {
        public int getX1();

        public int getX2();

        public int getX3();
    }

    public abstract class AbstractOutX implements OutX {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "x1: " + getX1() + " x2: " + getX2() + " x3: " + getX3();
        }
    }

    public class OutXA extends AbstractOutX {
        private final OutA a;

        public OutXA(OutA a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public int getX1() {
            return a.getA1() + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getX2() {
            return a.getA2() + a.getA3() + 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getX3() {
            return a.getA1() + a.getA2() + 3;
        }
    }

    public class OutXAB extends AbstractOutX {
        private final OutA a;
        private final OutB b;

        public OutXAB(OutA a, OutB b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public int getX1() {
            return a.getA1() + b.getB1();
        }

        @Override
        public int getX2() {
            return a.getA2() * b.getB2();
        }

        @Override
        public int getX3() {
            return (int) Math.pow(a.getA3(), b.getB3());
        }
    }

    public class OutXFactory {
        public OutX create(In in, CSVType type) {
            if (type == CSVType.TYPE_1) {
                OutA a = new OutA(in);
                return new OutXA(a);
            } else {
                OutA a = new OutA(in);
                OutB b = new OutB(a);
                return new OutXAB(a, b);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm... A few problems though: `OutA` is not immutable anymore, it directly depends on `In` and the computation is tightly coupled with it. I'll think about it, it might be adaptable to my case, no pun intended :) Tnx!!

Comment: `OutA`s `In` is final so it is immutable.  The calculations are indeed within `OutA` since `OutA` knows how to calculate a value.  This keeps the **data and behavior (the calculation) within the object**.  Your original posted code has a long method since it's effectively procedural code wrapped in a class.  See: tell, don't ask.

Comment: To be immutable, `OutA` needs to have all its member variables `final` and `a3` is not anymore (put `a3 = null` in `getA2()` and you have a huge bug that would otherwise be prevented). `OutA` should not contain calculations themselves - how would you have multiple variants of calculations, by injecting services into the data bean and have `getXXX` call them? I don't think that's a good idea... Consider sending `OutA` via over HTTP. How would clients calculate the values, by having the whole service setup on their end?

Comment: Sorry - you're right - `OutA` is not immutable because of `a3`.  Does it matter though, since `a3` is not visible outside the class?  I updated my answer with a more interesting example using a factory to have different calculations but still use the same `OutX` interface.  Concerning sending the result to a client, probably a simple class to pass the result.